# How can I view the backup logs of Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to view the logs of when backups of Azure SQL were taken? Success, failure, etc, logs or logs of the PITR, LTR, diffs being taken?

I can see a list of our available LTRs, but I don't seem to see any log history of when these things were made, etc.

This is not SQL on Azure VMs, I'm using their fully managed Azure SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure SQL Database auditing to track database events and writes them to an audit log in your Azure storage account, or sends them to Event Hub or Log Analytics for downstream processing and analysis.

You can use SQL Database auditing to:

Retain an audit trail of selected events. You can define categories of database actions to be audited.
Report on database activity. You can use pre-configured reports and a dashboard to get started quickly with activity and event reporting.
Analyze reports. You can find suspicious events, unusual activity, and trends.

Find the detailed source document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview#setup-auditing) to know more.

[Set up auditing for your server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview#setup-auditing) tutorial here.

Comment: Do you know if this includes logs regarding the database backups? When they are taken, ideally? I don't see anything about backups.

Comment: Yes. You need to configure diagnostic settings and use log analytics for auditing. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/configure-reports

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: no PITR backup events can be seen when auditing Azure SQL DB events. Even  when choosing "BACKUP_RESTORE_GROUP" as an "AuditActionGroup" I have not seen PITR backups tracked as audit events :(  /As a note: Azure Monitor is not supported to be used for Audit events with Azure SQL, it has to be enabled from "Security/Auditing" blade, but this does not help with PITR Backup events./

The only way to track PITR backup events is via TSQL described in this article: [Azure SQL DB Backup History - View backups of your Azure SQL Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/azure-sql-db-backup-history-view-backups-of-your-azure-sql/ba-p/3279882)